# Crystal Report: Sum Up a Column With Respect to value in other column

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I Want to Sum Up A Column say (column1) in crystal report with respect to the value in column2.

```
     EG:

     Column1        Column2

       10            SR
        5            SR
       20            ZR
```

I want to sum up column1 When Column2 value is 'SR'.
Out put should be '15' and not '35'.
How Do i Achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

assuming column 1 and 2 are fields from your table.

```
 if {tablefield1} = 'SR' then {tablefield2} else 0
```

Summary Sum to the report or group foot